# R legend only showing first item

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

Here is my R code and below is the resulting plot.

```
ggplot(Data,aes(x=P, y=T, colour=Study , fill=Method, shape=Direction)) 
+ geom_point(size=2, alpha=0.5) 
+ scale_shape_manual(values=c(22,23,24),labels=c("1","2","3")) 
+ scale_colour_manual(values=cp2,labels=cp2) 
+ scale_fill_manual(values=c("white","black"),labels=c("1","2"))
```

Why is the legend only showing the first value for shape and showing incorrect values for fill (the second should be empty)?

Also, should I be using *discrete* instead of *manual*?

(I'm using RStudio Version 0.98.1091 and R version 3.1.2 on 64 bit Windows 7)

**EDIT** I realise now that the symbols appear correctly in the exported image (I hadn't noticed!) ... it's only in RStudio that the symbols don't work (the fill issue persists but is resolved using the answers from [Ben Bolker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/190277/ben-bolker) or [lukeA](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1327739/lukea) below).
[image: Output from R]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This (reproducible) example gets you partway there, by using `guide_legend()` with `override.aes` to set the point type for the `fill` legend to one that actually uses a filled background.  For your other questions, it would help if you could clarify what you're expecting the `shape` (in this case `gear`) legend to look like.

Load package:

```
library("ggplot2")
```

Modify built-in `mtcars` data frame:

```
mm <- transform(mtcars,
                am=factor(am),
                gear=factor(gear),
                carb=factor(carb>1),
                cyl=factor(cyl))
theme_set(theme_classic())  ## blank background

ggplot(mm,
       aes(x=wt, y=mpg, colour=cyl,
           fill=carb, shape=gear))+
             geom_point(size=2, alpha=0.5)+
               scale_shape_manual(values=c(22,23,24))+
               scale_fill_manual(values=c("white","black"),
                   guide=guide_legend(override.aes=list(shape=22)))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can override this odd behaviour by manipulating the legend using `override.aes`:

```
library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(x = runif(12), y = runif(12), fill = gl(2, 6), colour = gl(4, 3), shape = gl(3, 4))
ggplot(df, aes(x, y, fill = fill, colour = colour, shape = shape)) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("white","black"),labels=c("1","2")) +
  geom_point(size=10, alpha=0.5) + 
  scale_shape_manual(values=c(22,23,24),labels=c("1","2","3")) + 
  guides(shape = guide_legend(override.aes = list(alpha = 1)), 
         fill = guide_legend(override.aes = list(colour = c("black", "white"))))
```